# MS Access: Best indexing strategy for retrieving DISTINCT combinations of joined fields

Tags: sql, ms-access, indexing, ms-access-2010

I have two tables in MS Access 2010:

**Table tblA:**

```
idA AutoNumber
a Text(255)
b Text(255)
c Text(255)
x Text(255)
y Text(255)
```

**Table tblB:**

```
idB AutoNumber
fkA Long Integer
d Text(255)
e Text(255)
z Text(255)
```

... and need to execute the following query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
  tblA.a
, tblA.b
, tblA.c
, tblB.d
, tblB.e
FROM tblA
INNER JOIN tblB
  on tblA.idA = tblB.fkA
;
```

Both tables are very large and I was wondering what is the best indexing strategy to achieve the fastest response time. 
idA and idB are the primary keys for their respective tables and fkA has its own index. 
But what about tblA.a, tblA.b, tblA.c, tblB.d, tblB.e? Should I create a composite index on tblA.a, tblA.b, tblA.c and one on tblB.d, tblB.e? Or should each field be indexed individually?

I tried both options and the first one seems to yield slightly better results, though both are not very satisfactory in terms of performance. I would like to understand more about the theoretical background and appreciate every input.

Comment: BTW: `DISTINCT` is  a costly operation. I suppose you do have duplicates in the values selected and hence need it. If you don't, remove it from your query.

Comment: MS Access far from being a great DBMS. If you do need `DISTINCT` then you might gain speed by joining distinct values (and thus reducing the intermediate result): `from tblA join (select distinct fkA, d, e from tblB) b on ...` (and then remove `DISTINCT` from the original select clause of course).

Comment: @ThorstenKettner, interesting approach, I'll give it a try! Though a, b, c, d, and e might contain NULLs in my case, which makes joining a hassle.

Comment: You'd still join on on idA = fkA. No difference hence.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you are joining *all* records, the DBMS may simply decide for full table scans to join the tables.

With indexes on `tblA(idA)` and `tblB(fkA)` you give the DBMS the option to use these instead, but it's up to the DBMS to do so or not (it will - hopefully - decide for the faster way, whichever this is).

You can also offer the DBMS covering indexes. That means all columns used in the query are in that index, so if the DBMS uses it, it doesn't have to access the table additionally, but can get everything from the index itself. As you have no where clause, the DBMS may still prefer to access the tables row by row, rather than run through indexes. The covering indexes would be:

- `tblA(idA, a, b, c)`
- `tblB(fkA, d, e)`

Comment: Thanks for you answer! Since idA is already indexed (being the primary key), would I still have to add it to the covering index, or would it be enough to create a composite index on a, b, c?

Comment: The database uses one index per table in a query. So you must build complete indexes; you must not omit `idA` in the covering index. Moreover this should be the first column in the index, because this is the accessing column used for the join.

Comment: Thorsten, your answer helped me a lot to speed things up, thanks for that! However, I have noticed that Access does not allow the creation of indexes spanning more than 10 fields. If I need to DISTINCT, say, 15 fields and I have a covered index on 10 of them, will the covered index give any performance advantage or only create additional overhead when modifying data?

Comment: No. Covering indexes cover all columns mentioned in the select. So when the DBMS uses the index, it doesn't have to access the table anymore. If only one column is missing in the index, then the table records must be read, too.

Comment: The query you describe is very special, by the way. To combine all records of two big tables and then get rid of all duplicates in the result set. Wow, that is quite a task and feels a bit weird actually. Maybe there is something wrong with the table design or what you want to achieve with this query can be achieved otherwise somehow. You may want to open another request and describe in more detail what your tables contain and what you want to do with the query result. Sometimes the real answer lies somewhere where we don't suppose it to be :-)